# How to disable the highligting of the location of the mouse pointer? Screen dimming with a bright circle around the pointer

Tags: windows-10, powertoys

How to disable the highligting of the location of the mouse pointer? It's the one where the screen gets dim except for a bright circle around the mouse pointer. I am not sure what keyboard and mouse combination is activating it. It's related to pressing the ctrl key but whenever I test it by pressing the key and mouse clicking, it doesn't happen.

I thought it was the Windows PowerToys doing it but I uninstall it and it's still happening.
I don't know if it's a Windows feature or an app doing it plus I don't know how to make it happen on demand. It happens several times during the day while in different apps and I try to remember what I just did to activate it but it looks like ctrl + left mouse click.

I am hoping someone knows what's causing it.

Comment: What mouse? Try a simpler mouse. No issue here Windows 10 or 11, Ubuntu or Kali. Logitech Bluetooth mouse (nice and simple).

Comment: Doesn't sound like a Windows feature. Windows has mouse rings, which can be triggered using *Ctrl* when enabled.

Comment: @john. I have been using the same mouse for years on two computers. This seems to have started this year when I installed the Powertoys. I have this issue on both computers now.

Comment: See if there is anything in this Power Toys article that may help you.  ....   https://www.howtogeek.com/665780/all-microsofts-powertoys-for-windows-10-explained/

Comment: This is definitely not native to windows, but it is possible its a feature of your mouse itself. Did you install its mouse drivers?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it by:

- Opening PowerToys' settings
- Going to Mouse utilities
- Setting `Enable Find My Mouse` to Off

[image]